# tcc: Use C standard functions in assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, tcc

I have simple assembly files created by *NASM*. I want to link them with `tcc`. For debugging I want to use `printf()` in my assembly code. But when I do so, `tcc` fails with `tcc: undefined symbol 'printf'`.

Here is a minimal example code to reproduce the error:

```
extern printf
hello: db "Hello world!",0

global main
main:
    push hello
    call printf
    pop eax
ret
```

Console:

```
nasm -felf hello.asm
tcc hello.o
```

> ```
> tcc: undefined symbol 'printf'
> ```

When I use `gcc hello.o` everything works fine, so it has to be a tcc specific problem. How do I get this to work with tcc?

Edit: I'm using a Windows version of *NASM* and *TCC* to generate 32-bit Windows executables.

Comment: Maybe tcc mangles names, you could try `_printf` instead. Alternatively look in the actual tcc libraries or compile a test C program and look at the (dis)assembly for that.

Comment: @Jester it's not tcc that would decorate names, it's the platform's ABI. And yes, Windows' ABI does decorate names.

Comment: @fuz just because he is on windows, doesn't mean he is using windows ABI. Hint: `-f elf`.

Comment: @Jester Oh yeah. Even weirder! Why is OP using ELF on Windows? Perhaps he is using WSL, but he would have surely told us.

Comment: @Jester When I look up the names with e.g. `nm -g` they are exactly the same in both files. From the disassembly I can't see a diference between the object files. `_printf`causes the same error.

Comment: @fuz I'm using elf since tcc does not recognise `-fwin32` and some other nasm options. Is it possible that this is the problem?

Comment: @kaetzacoatl Possibly! Are you programming on WSL?

Comment: @fuz No, it's a normal windows installation.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl WSL (Windows services for Linux) is available on normal Windows installations. I am asking because all of this really looks like you are using WSL (that subsystem which allows Linux programs to run on Windows).

Comment: @fuz I can't run Linux programs on my system. Both nasm and tcc are normal windows applications (.exe). And tcc creates an .exe file by default. I'm only using elf for my object files since tcc requires them in elf format.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl I see. Can tcc compile C programs that use `printf`? Why are you using tcc in the first place?

Comment: The issue seems to be that TCC is being anal about the type of symbols in the ELF objects when trying to link. NASM creates extern labels like `printf` with the NO_TYPE attribute but it appears that TCC demands they be a FUNCTION type. I happened to compile a C file (that calls `printf`) and compared that object to your _NASM_ object. The only difference was the type attributed to the symbol. If I used a hex editor to change the type manually it was able to find `printf` properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that *TCC* requires specific type information on functions that are external linkage like `printf`. By default *NASM* creates references to symbols with a *NOTYPE* attribute in the *ELF* objects. This appears to confuse *TCC* as it seems to expect external function symbols to be marked with a *FUNCTION* type.

---

I discovered this by taking the simple *C* program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("hello\n");
}
```

and compiling it to an object file (*TCC* uses *ELF* objects by default) with a command like:

```
tcc -c simple.c
```

This generates `simple.o`. I happened to use *OBJDUMP* to display the assembly code and *ELF* headers. I didn't see anything unusual in the code but the symbol table in the headers showed a difference. If you use the program *READELF* you can get a detailed dump of the symbols.

```
readelf -s simple.o
```

> ```
> Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
>    Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
>      0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
>      1: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS simple.c
>      2: 00000000     7 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 L.0
>      3: 00000000    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
>      4: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf
> ```

Of particular interest is the symbol table entry for `printf`:

> ```
>     4: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf
> ```

If you were to dump the *ELF* headers for your `hello.o` object you'd seem something similar to this:

```
readelf -s hello.o
```

> ```
> Symbol table '.symtab' contains 6 entries:
>    Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
>      0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
>      1: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS hello.asm
>      2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
>      3: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 hello
>      4: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf
>      5: 0000000d     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
> ```

Notice how the symbol `printf` in `hello.o` differs from the one  in `simple.o` above. *NASM* defines labels by default using *NOTYPE* attribute rather than a *FUNCTION* .

---

### Use YASM instead of NASM

I don't know of any way to resolve the problem in *NASM* since I don't know a way to force it to use a *FUNCTION* type and not *NOTYPE* on a symbol defined as `extern`. I changed the type in a hex editor and it linked and ran as expected.

One alternative is to [download *YASM*](http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html) (a rewrite of *NASM*). For the *most* part *NASM* and *YASM* work the same. *YASM*'s command line is mostly compatible with *NASM* so you should be able to use it as a direct replacement. *YASM* has an extra feature that allows you to specify the type of a symbol with the [`type` directive](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-elf-directives.html):

> ```
> 9.3.3. TYPE: Set symbol type
>
> ELF’s symbol table has the capability of indicating whether a symbol is a
> function or data. While this can be specified directly in the GLOBAL
> directive (see Section 9.4), the TYPE directive allows specifying the
> symbol type for any symbol, including local symbols.
>
> The directive takes two parameters; the first parameter is the symbol
> name, and the second is the symbol type. The symbol type must be either
> function or object. An unrecognized type will cause a warning to be
> generated. Example of use:
>
> func:
>         ret
> type func function
> section .data
> var dd 4
> type var object
> ```

You'd only have to add an extra line of type information to your assembly code for each external function you use. Your assembly code could be modified to look like:

```
extern printf
type printf function

hello: db "Hello world!",0

global main
main:
    push hello
    call printf
    pop eax
ret
```

It should compile and link with this:

```
yasm -felf hello.asm -o hello.o
tcc hello.o -o hello.exe
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know what the problem is. I really wonder, why nasm does not support something like `extern printf:function`, which would fix the problem. I'll look if it is possible to do something on the tcc side, but I'm afraid that this wont help. Probably I have to change either my assembler or my compiler.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl Changing the assembler between Nasm and Yasm is very easy. A link to the Yasm download is in my answer. Probably easiest thing to do without changing to a completely different tool chain like gcc. Just download the yasm executable rename it to yasm.exe and put it in the same directory as NASM would be simplest. Then you can just use yasm on the command line rather than nasm.

Comment: I would report this as a bug to the tcc team.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl I don't know why _NASM_ doesn't support declaring a type when defining an external label (using `extern`). It is allowed when defining global labels like `global main:function` but this isn't supported  `extern printf:function`

Comment: As @fuz points out one could consider this a bug with _TCC_. You can submit a bug (and review existing open bugs) on their [bug tracking system](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc/)